# Duplicate every element of array via streams in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have some array

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

How can I get another array from this with duplicate elements via streams. 
I mean something like this

```
result = Stream.of(a).map(...)
// after that result = {1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need a `flatMap` instead of a `map`. Like,

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] result = IntStream.of(a).flatMap(x -> IntStream.of(x, x)).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

Comment: Excuse me. I can't ask another question in 90 minutes. 
Can you help me with another case. 
What if a is array of array
int[][] a = {{1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 4}, {2, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 2}, {4, 2, 1}};

Comment: @АртурГудиев That's quite a different case, and before anyone can answer it - you'd have to tell us what result you would expect. Also, actually try and apply the answers you got here to that question.

Comment: I need from every {x,y,z} array to get 2 array {x,y,z} and {y,x,z}. In other words, I make the graph undirected.

Comment: @АртурГудиев It's been all of 50 minutes, but ok. It's not trivial to construct an array of arrays with a stream. You ***could*** do `Object[] b = IntStream.range(0, a.length)
    .mapToObj(x -> new int[][] { { a[x][0], a[x][1], a[x][2] }, { a[x][1], a[x][0], a[x][2] } })
    .toArray();` which should produce your desired array.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to go about it:

```
int[] result = Arrays.stream(a)
                     .flatMap(e -> IntStream.of(e,e))
                     .toArray();
```

or:

```
int[] result = Arrays.stream(a)
                     .flatMap(e -> IntStream.generate(() -> e).limit(2))
                     .toArray();
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. Unfortunately, another man was earlier so I will mark his answer as correct. But if I can mark you both I will do it

Comment: @АртурГудиев please accept Elliott's he posted it before me :).

Comment: Excuse me. Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to ask another question in 90 minutes. Can you help me with case of array of arrays. 
int[][] a = {{1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 4}, {2, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 2}, {4, 2, 1}};
IntStream doesn't work in this case

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help you

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(a), Arrays.stream(a)).sorted().forEach(element -> System.out.print(element));
```